# Could the laws of physics have existed before the universe?

Tags: cosmology, universe, big-bang, laws-of-physics

Alexander Vilenkin writes that perhaps the laws of physics could have existed even before the universe emerged from nothing.

1. How could the laws of physics exist without the existence of the universe that they describe?
2. What does "from nothing" mean?

Comment: This is a very interesting question, but it's a philosophy, not a physics question.

Comment: Related post  by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/603323/2451

Comment: *Where* do laws exist?

Comment: “Nothing” means a state with no space, no time, no matter, no radiation, and no energy.

Comment: @G. Smith Is such a state possible? And if possible, it is still a physical state, it exists.

Comment: Some physicists think such a state is possible. This is speculative stuff for now, not widely-accepted physics. A good theory of quantum gravity may eventually help clarify whether this is possible.

Comment: In string theory this is called a non-coherent state, as far as I remember.